# In cancan, how to check if can? manage each and every record for a given model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

1. My admin `can :manage, Widget`
2. My user `can :manage, Widget, :user_id => user.id`
3. In my view, I want to show a link only if the current_user can manage *each and every* Widget record.

Answer (score 0):

In general?

`can? :manage, Widget`

If you're referring to some check on existing records, that sounds like a design flaw, but this should work. Note that if this is the approach you're taking, you have a race condition with other `Widget` records being created after you make this check.

`(can? :manage, Widget) || (Widget.count == Widget.count(:conditions => ["user_id == ?", current_user.id]))`

Comment: It is my understanding that can?(:manage, Widget) ignores conditions and simply returns true.  If that is the case, then neither of your solutions will correctly return false when current_user is not an admin.

Comment: Did you try it? The `can?` method in a view is applied to the current_user based on what you have defined in your abilities class.

Comment: I tried `if can? :manage, Widget` but sadly it returns true for user and admin alike.

Comment: Probably time to post some real code then, because what you're describing should work.